# How to instantiate ViewController and retain the navigation bar at the top of the ViewController presented?

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

In a TabBar controller I have multiple ViewControllers. I would like to access `MediaDetailTableViewController` from `ProfileTVC` and pass some data to it without using segues.
The schema of the StoryBoard is like this:

Tab Bar
 1. Nav -> NewsFeed -> MediaDetailTableViewController
 2. Nav - > ProfileTVC
From ProfileTVC I want to instantiate  MediaDetailTableViewController and pass some data to it.
Using the method shown below it passes the data, but it looses the navigation bar at the top, thus I can't go back to  `ProfileTVC`. Also, it takes about 2 seconds to instantiate MediaDetailTableViewController.

```
//code inside ProfileTVC
 if let selectedIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
        selectedIndex.section != 0 && selectedIndex.section != 1 {
 let mediaDetailTVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MediaDetailTableViewController") as! MediaDetailTableViewController
    mediaDetailTVC.currentUser = currentUser
    mediaDetailTVC.media = media[selectedIndex.section]
       self.present(mediaDetailTVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Comment: `Also, it takes about 2 seconds to instantiate MediaDetailTableViewController.` Then you need to stop right now and worry first and foremost about why _that_ is.

Comment: Thanks matt. I shall pay more attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PUSH instead of present

```
self.navigationController.push(mediaDetailTVC....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Much more simple!

> performSegue(withIdentifier:"MediaDetailTableViewController", sender: self)